# Why do I always have to reassign appended materials when starting blender?

Tags: materials, linked-data, append

I have appended some materials from blender file A to blender file B. In file B, I have assigned the materials to some objects and additionally added fake users just to be on the safe side. However, the materials are no longer assigned when I restart blender. I always have to re-assign them one by one. Ideas and suggestions are very much appreciated.

https://we.tl/t-vXdu80Gvsy

Comment: This should work from your description. Maybe looking in the files will answer your question, can you provide a simple example?

Comment: @Crantisz I added the link now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know how you miss this, but UI is blocked, notifying that material could not be assigned.

[image]

Dropdown box works, but I'm pretty sure that it is a bug, I suppose it should not work, until you will make a local copy of object (button right of the object name):

[image]

I don't know why you cannot override materials, maybe it's not implemented.